# How do I access the Google Apps Email Settings API using the google-api-ruby-client?

Tags: ruby, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-api-ruby-client

I want to be able to access these APIs: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/. I attempted to look at the discovered_apis and I have no clue which one I need to use in order to access "Google Apps Email Settings API"

```
client.discovered_apis.each { |x| puts "#{x.title} :: #{x.id} :: #{x.preferred}" }
Ad Exchange Buyer API :: adexchangebuyer:v1 :: false
Ad Exchange Buyer API :: adexchangebuyer:v1.1 :: false
Ad Exchange Buyer API :: adexchangebuyer:v1.2 :: false
Ad Exchange Buyer API :: adexchangebuyer:v1.3 :: true
Ad Exchange Seller API :: adexchangeseller:v1 :: false
Ad Exchange Seller API :: adexchangeseller:v1.1 :: true
Admin Directory API :: admin:directory_v1 :: false
Email Migration API v2 :: admin:email_migration_v2 :: false
Admin Reports API :: admin:reports_v1 :: true
AdSense Management API :: adsense:v1.2 :: false
AdSense Management API :: adsense:v1.3 :: false
AdSense Management API :: adsense:v1.4 :: true
AdSense Host API :: adsensehost:v4.1 :: true
Google Analytics API :: analytics:v2.4 :: false
Google Analytics API :: analytics:v3 :: true
Google Play Android Developer API :: androidpublisher:v1 :: false
Google Play Android Developer API :: androidpublisher:v1.1 :: true
Google App State API :: appstate:v1 :: true
Enterprise Audit API :: audit:v1 :: true
BigQuery API :: bigquery:v2 :: true
Blogger API :: blogger:v2 :: false
Blogger API :: blogger:v3 :: true
Books API :: books:v1 :: true
Calendar API :: calendar:v3 :: true
Google Civic Information API :: civicinfo:us_v1 :: true
Compute Engine API :: compute:v1 :: true
Compute Engine API :: compute:v1beta16 :: false
Google Maps Coordinate API :: coordinate:v1 :: true
CustomSearch API :: customsearch:v1 :: true
Google Cloud Datastore API :: datastore:v1beta1 :: false
Google Cloud Datastore API :: datastore:v1beta2 :: true
DFA Reporting API :: dfareporting:v1 :: false
DFA Reporting API :: dfareporting:v1.1 :: false
DFA Reporting API :: dfareporting:v1.2 :: false
DFA Reporting API :: dfareporting:v1.3 :: true
APIs Discovery Service :: discovery:v1 :: true
DoubleClick Bid Manager API :: doubleclickbidmanager:v1 :: true
DoubleClick Search API :: doubleclicksearch:v2 :: true
Drive API :: drive:v1 :: false
Drive API :: drive:v2 :: true
Freebase Search :: freebase:v1-sandbox :: false
Freebase Search :: freebase:v1sandbox :: false
Freebase Search :: freebase:v1 :: true
Fusion Tables API :: fusiontables:v1 :: true
Google Play Game Services API :: games:v1 :: true
Google Play Game Services Management API :: gamesManagement:v1management :: true
Google Affiliate Network API :: gan:v1beta1 :: true
Groups Migration API :: groupsmigration:v1 :: true
Groups Settings API :: groupssettings:v1 :: true
Google Identity Toolkit API :: identitytoolkit:v3 :: true
Enterprise License Manager API :: licensing:v1 :: true
Google Maps Engine API :: mapsengine:v1 :: true
Google Mirror API :: mirror:v1 :: true
Google OAuth2 API :: oauth2:v1 :: false
Google OAuth2 API :: oauth2:v2 :: true
Orkut API :: orkut:v2 :: true
PageSpeed Insights API :: pagespeedonline:v1 :: true
Google+ API :: plus:v1 :: true
Google+ Domains API :: plusDomains:v1 :: true
Prediction API :: prediction:v1.2 :: false
Prediction API :: prediction:v1.3 :: false
Prediction API :: prediction:v1.4 :: false
Prediction API :: prediction:v1.5 :: false
Prediction API :: prediction:v1.6 :: true
QPX Express API :: qpxExpress:v1 :: true
Enterprise Apps Reseller API :: reseller:v1sandbox :: false
Enterprise Apps Reseller API :: reseller:v1 :: true
Search API For Shopping :: shopping:v1 :: true
Google Site Verification API :: siteVerification:v1 :: true
Google Spectrum Database API :: spectrum:v1explorer :: true
Cloud SQL Administration API :: sqladmin:v1beta1 :: false
Cloud SQL Administration API :: sqladmin:v1beta3 :: true
Cloud Storage API :: storage:v1beta1 :: false
Cloud Storage API :: storage:v1beta2 :: true
TaskQueue API :: taskqueue:v1beta1 :: false
TaskQueue API :: taskqueue:v1beta2 :: true
Tasks API :: tasks:v1 :: true
Translate API :: translate:v2 :: true
URL Shortener API :: urlshortener:v1 :: true
Google Fonts Developer API :: webfonts:v1 :: true
YouTube Data API :: youtube:v3 :: true
YouTube Analytics API :: youtubeAnalytics:v1 :: true
YouTube Analytics API :: youtubeAnalytics:v1beta1 :: false
```

Comment: Did you ever discover a workaround here?